# Creating new columns using loop in R

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

Consider the following data named `df`:

```
id  v1  v2
1    3  3,4,5,3,4,5
2    2  4,5,4
3    5  5,5,5
4    3  3,3,4
5    4  4,4,6,7
```

Now, I want to create new data set with new columns using `loop`. The column names are derived from the last column (`v2`). That means it starts from `v3` (the smallest value in `v2`) and ends at `v7` (the largest value in `v2`). The value of each cell of newly created columns is the number of times that number is repeated in `v2`. My new data set looks like the following:

```
id  v1   v3   v4   v5   v6  v7
1    3    2    2    2    0   0
2    2    0    2    1    0   0
3    5    0    0    3    0   0
4    3    2    1    0    0   0
5    4    0    2    0    1   1
```

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the 'v2' column is `character` class, split the column by `,` and use `qdapTools::mtabulate` to get the frequencies

```
library(qdapTools)
df[paste0("v", 3:7)] <- mtabulate(strsplit(df$v2, ","))
df$v2 <- NULL
```

-output

```
> df
  id v1 v3 v4 v5 v6 v7
1  1  3  2  2  2  0  0
2  2  2  0  2  1  0  0
3  3  5  0  0  3  0  0
4  4  3  2  1  0  0  0
5  5  4  0  2  0  1  1
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(id = 1:5, v1 = c(3L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 4L), v2 = c("3,4,5,3,4,5", 
"4,5,4", "5,5,5", "3,3,4", "4,4,6,7")), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```